# Tiger-Tribe Hunter and temporary power/toughness changes

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack, mtg-arena, mtg-drafting

I played AFR draft on MTG Arena last night and encountered something that doesn't make sense to me.

My opponent had a [Zombie Ogre](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/129/zombie-ogre) with a +1/+1 counter and a [Death-Priest of Myrkul](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/95/death-priest-of-myrkul) in play. I had a [Targ Nar, Demon-Fang Gnoll](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/234/targ-nar-demon-fang-gnoll) and a [Tiger-Tribe Hunter](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/163/tiger-tribe-hunter).

In my precombat main phase, I doubled Targ Nar's power and toughness twice, making it an 8/8. I declared both of my creatures as attackers and sacrificed him to Tiger-Tribe Hunter's triggered ability (targeting Zombie Ogre). Only 2 damage got applied to Zombie Ogre, but I was expecting it to be lethal.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: The latest update for JumpStart Horizons has a reputation as being quite buggy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That is a bug. It should deal 8 damage.**

Tiger-Tribe Hunter has a ruling that says

> Use the sacrificed creature's power as it last existed on the battlefield to determine how much damage is dealt.

Targ Nar's power was 8 when it was last on the battlefield, so the Tiger-Tribe Hunter should deal 8 damage.

This problem with Tiger-Tribe Hunter has been [reported as a bug](https://feedback.wizards.com/forums/918667-mtg-arena-bugs-product-suggestions/suggestions/44048028-tiger-tribe-hunter-dealt-the-wrong-amount-of-damag) by several other people on the official Magic: Arena bug reporting website.